# How to fully maintain a bicycle myself?

Tags: maintenance, mechanical

I'm into bikes for a long time, but I still haven't got how to do maintenance of the bicycle myself so I only know how to change a tire and put some grease on the chain. I'd like to know the list of stuff I should check in my bike and how to fix/update it in different situation. 
I know, it's a really deep question that need a lot of typing, so I rather expect you share some links on reliable sources that fully cover the question.

Comment: Part of the reason we don't like link-answer questions is that link-rot will mean that most of the links will break in a few years. This is also why we prefer more focused questions that can be answered in-text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Park tools publishes a book on bicycle repair and maintenance: [Big Blue Book of Bicycle Repair](http://www.parktool.com/product/big-blue-book-of-bicycle-repair-3rd-edition-bbb-3).

Park also has a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/parktoolcompany) and [Repair Help Articles](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help).

Global Cycling Network has some [maintenance videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=gcn%20maintenance%20monday) on their YouTube channel

Performance Bicycles has maintenance videos on their [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/PerformanceBikes).

Also [MBR Magazine YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/MBRmagazine).

For some good places to start, try:

[GCN's 5 Essential Bike Maintenance Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TIlNAXU1kk)

[GCN's The 1 Hour Tune Up - How To Make Your Bike Feel Like New](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYaeVDnSK2c)

[MBR's How to Carry Out Basic Mountain Bike Maintenance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCX1a-7Edmk)

Comment: There's also a Haynes book, which does include a section on service intervals.

Comment: Park also has how-to guides for most jobs. A simple approach is to buy tools as needed.

Comment: @whatsisname thanks, added link to Park's repair help articles to my answer

Comment: Don't forget Leonard Zinn's excellent books, including [Zinn and the Art of Road Bike Maintenance](https://www.velopress.com/books/zinn-the-art-of-road-bike-maintenance/) and [Zinn and the Art of Mountain Bike Maintenance](https://www.velopress.com/books/zinn-the-art-of-mountain-bike-maintenance/).  I have the road bike book and it's great.